# HTML tags in Eclipse editor hover

Tags: html, eclipse, hover

I creating an editor for my own language in Eclipse. In this language, there are javadoc-like documentation comments. I'm using class `ITextHover` to show this documentation when the mouse cursor is above name of the commented function.

The problem is that my documentation contains basic HTML tags (list, table, bold) but the hover shows only plain text. For example:

[image: a screenshot of an example documentation showed in a hover]

Of course, I would like it to look like this:

[image: an image with a properly formatted hover]

I know for sure that this kind of text formatting in a hover can be handled by eclipse because e.g. Java editor does that.

Unfortunately, the only clue I found so far is to use class `IInformationPresenter` and I can't found any information about what this class does or how to use it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ITextHover` class should implement `ITextHoverExtension` and return an `IInformationControl` that can handle HTML. The standard `DefaultInformationControl` handles simple HTML.

An example is the text hover from the standard text editor:

```
class TextHover extends DefaultTextHover implements ITextHoverExtension {
    public TextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        super(sourceViewer);
    }

    ... other stuff ...

    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {
            @Override
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                return new DefaultInformationControl(parent, EditorsUI.getTooltipAffordanceString());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i was putting quite time into a solution i just post it here so perhaps someone may find it helpful:

```
public static class DocumentationInformationControl extends AbstractInformationControl implements IInformationControlExtension3,IInformationControlExtension5{

    private Browser fBrowser;
    private String input;

    public DocumentationInformationControl(Shell parent) {
        super(parent,true);
        create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void createContent(Composite parent) {
        fBrowser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
        fBrowser.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInformation(String input) {
        super.setInformation(input);
        this.input = input;
        fBrowser.setText(input);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasContents() {
        return StringUtils.isNoneBlank(input);
    }
    
    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getInformationPresenterControlCreator() {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {

            @Override
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                return new DocumentationInformationControl(parent);
            }
        };
    }

    
}
```

The interfaces and the presenter here a just to tell the underlaying framework that the tooltip/popup is to keep open(reshown) when hover over it losing the mouse-hover of the primar object itself.